# Submit form on keypess after verification

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//attach keypress event listener to the whole document
$(document).keypress(function(event){
if(event.keyCode === 13){
SearchThis.submit();
return false;
}
});

});
```

So now my form (SearchThis) is submitted whenever the enter key is pressed which is great however how do I modify it to check if mysearchfied has been completed before it submits?

IE. If mysearchfied is empty and the enter key is pressed don't submit the form. If mysearchfied contains text and the enter key is pressed then submit the form.

Hope you can help! Thanks...

Comment: how mysearchfield look like ?

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mysearchfield" value="" id="mysearchfield" placeholder="Company or SmartPages Category..." autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
listenOn = function(domElement) {
  domElement.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      onEnterPressed();
    }
  });

  function onEnterPressed() {
    if (validateForm()) {
      submitForm();
    } else {
      alert('Invalid form');
    }
  }

  function validateForm() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    return (inputValue.length >= 1);
  }

  function submitForm() {
    var formElement = document.getElementById("myForm");
    alert('Submit form');
    formElement.submit();
  }
}

listenOn(document);
//listenOn(document.getElementById("myForm")); //You could also listen keydowns on form element(sure only if global keypress isn't exactly what you want).
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#send.php">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="I'm empty now." />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to validate the textbox for required use HTML5 `required attribute` like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="mysearchfield" 
value="" id="mysearchfield" placeholder="Company or SmartPages   Category..." autocomplete="off" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {   

    if ($('mysearchfied_ID_or_Class').val()!=='') {
          //mysearchfied is not empty
             SearchThis.submit();
    }  
    else {
         //dont submit, do your checks
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input but it is not working. With text in mysearchfield and leaving the input field and pressing enter whilst on the page does not submit the form

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to validate the form.

->  Check is the form valid usind the form valid function

```
 SearchThis.validate().valid()
```

-> validate each field for value as told by @n01ze

Answer (score 0):

if the id of your input field is mysearchfield, then you could do it like this:

```
var msf = document.getElementById("mysearchfield").value;

$(document).ready(function() {
//attach keypress event listener to the whole document
$(document).keypress(function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 13){

  if (msf != "") {
    SearchThis.submit();
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    // some code here....
  }
}
});

});
```

Comment: thanks for your input but it is not working. With text in mysearchfield and leaving the input field and pressing enter whilst on the page does not submit the form

Comment: There's something i noticed with your code. you've got triple (=) in this part: event.keyCode === 13